# ImageMagick command not found

Tags: macos, imagemagick, path-variables

I installed ImageMagick for Mac OS X and set the path as was given in the instruction.

```
export MAGICK_HOME="$HOME/Desktop/code/ImageMagick-6.8.9"
export PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/bin:$PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$MAGICK_HOME/lib/"
```

and when echoed the PATH it showed

```
ishivendra:code shivendraagrawal$ echo $PATH
/Users/shivendraagrawal/Desktop/code/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/shivendraagrawal/anaconda/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

But using the command resulted in this

```
ishivendra:code shivendraagrawal$ convert 3.jpg -morphology Convolve DoG:15,100,0 -negate -normalize -blur 0x1 -channel RBG -level 60%,91%,0.1 5.jpg
-bash: convert: command not found
```

Where am I wrong here?

Comment: try writing `which convert`. It should give you the actual path where it will look for convert.

Comment: When I was just clicking the convert executable in the bin folder of the ImageMagick folder then a error mentioning "DyLd library not found..." was shown. I checked where it was searching for that DyLd library and copied the ImageMagick folder to the root where it was looking for the DyLd library. Now upon clicking the convert executable it runs, but not via the command line. Still saying " Command not found"